# Find the range of values for $a+b$ when $y=-\frac{1}{8}x^2+ax+b$ is tangent to the $x-$axis.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the function $$y=-\frac{1}{8}x^2+ax+b\tag{*}$$ I'm asked to find the range of values for $a+b$ when $y$ is tangent to the $x-$axis. I know the answer is $a+b\leq\frac{1}{8}$ but I haven't found a way to confirm it.

This is just the final part of the exercise. In the rest of it, I found the vertex $V(p,q)$ for (*), which coordinates are, $$p=4a, \hspace{10mm} q=2a^2+b,$$ and found that when $V$ lies on $x+y=1,$ then $b=-2a^2-4a+1$. This let us conclude that $\beta(a,b)=8a+b$ reaches its maximum at $(1,3).$ However I don't know how this information is useful to solve the last part of the exercise.

I tried to use the fact that the roots of (*) are,
$$x=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2+b/2}}{-1/4}$$ if $y$ is tangent to the $x-$axis, then $a^2+\frac{b}{2}=0$. But I don't know how to continue from here since I'm going to find an equality, not an inequality as I'm asked to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=-\frac{x^2}8+ax+b$, then $f'(x)=-\frac x4+a$, and therefore $f'(x)=0\iff x=4a$. So, since the graph of $f$ as tangent to the $x$-axis, $f(4a)=0$, which means that $b=-2a^2$. But then\begin{align}a+b&=a-2a^2\\&=-2\left(a-\frac14\right)^2+\frac18\end{align}and$$\left\{-2\left(a-\frac14\right)^2+\frac18\,\middle|\,a\in\Bbb R\right\}=\left(-\infty,\frac18\right].$$

Answer (score 1):

Given parabola is tangent to x-line iff it discriminat is $0$, so $$a^2+b/2 =0$$

So $f(a)=a+b = a-2a^2$ which is a quadratic function on $a$ and achieves the maximum at $a={1\over 4}$, so $f(a)\leq {1\over 4}-{1\over 8} = {1\over 8}$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=-\frac{1}{8}x^2 + ax +b. \\
f'(x)=-\frac{1}{4}x +a.\\
f'(x_0)=0 \Leftrightarrow x_0=4a.\\
f(x_0)=f(4a)=2a^2+b.\\
f(x_0)=0 \Leftrightarrow b=-2a^2.\\S(a, b)=a+b = a + (-2a^2).\\
S'(a, b)=-4a+1.\\
S'(a, b)=0 \Leftrightarrow a=\frac{1}{4}.\\
S(a, b) \le -2(\frac{1}{4})^2 + \frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{8}.
$